# Product of p-summable sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $1<p<\infty$ and $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be two complex, $p$-summable sequences, which means that \begin{equation} \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p < \infty, \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^p < \infty.\end{equation}
Let $(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence induced by the Cauchy product between $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, that is $c_n := \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}$. When is $(c_n)$ again p-summable ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hölder inequality should help. At first sight, $(c_n)$ is p-summable for $p=1/2$.

Comment: For $p=2$ simply use Cauchy-Schwarz. For $p \neq 2$, you should use Holder.

Comment: I don't think I can follow your reasoning. In my eyes, Cauchy-schwarz, as well as hölder, can only be used to show that the componentwise product $c_n=a_nb_n$ is 1-summable in some cases. This is not my setup